# Httpcontext.current is null outside of controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

At login every user I got, get assigned an CompanyId as a Claim. I can without problem reach this claim in the WebApiController. But if I try to reach it outside of the controller method, then HttpContext.Current becomes null.

How can I reach my claims outside of the controller, or what solution should I use to work with my identification?

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ProductRepository _productRepo = new ProductRepository();
    private readonly string companyId = MiniHelper.GetCompanyId();

    [Route("ProductList")]
    [EnableQuery()]
    public IQueryable<Product> GetProductList()
    {
        return _productRepo.GetProducts().AsQueryable().Where(u => u.UserId == companyId);
    }
}

public static class MiniHelper
{
    public static string GetCompanyId()
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
        if (identity == null)
            return string.Empty;
        return identity.Claims.Where(a => a.Type == "CompanyId").Select(v => v.Value).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HttpContext.Current is null because your trying to access it out of the HttpApplication processing pipeline.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application/_static/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application1.pdf

A simple solution would be to parse in the identity into your helper method as a parameter.